# Variables in one col; values in another->goal: add columns for variables

Tags: r, data-structures, dplyr, plyr

I think that I am facing a (hopefully) small problem but the search function is not providing any help for me. I am having trouble while extracting data via the OECD package. The Thing is, that I am getting a dataset in which all the variables are stored in one column. The dataset is in the long format, which is nice, but I want the variables to become single columns. At the moment the dataset looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the column "VAR" contains several variables: "B11","B12"...all in all 11 variables. All variables are measured for many countries (Col "COU"). What I would like to do is, do add new columns to the dataset that represent the single variables that are stored in "VAR" right now and contain the corresponding values of the "obsValue" column?

So that I can see the value for B11 e.g. for Afghanistan 1999 in one row, for 2000 in another but also the value for B12 in 1999 in the same row as the one for B11 and so on. I hope the my aim is getting clear, if not, do not hesitate to ask.

Here is Code to reproduce the head of the dataset:

```
dput(head(MIG,20)) 

structure(list(CO2 = c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG"), VAR = c("B11", "B11", "B11", 
"B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", 
"B11", "B11", "B11", "B11", "B12", "B12", "B12", "B12"), GEN = c("WMN", 
"WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", 
"WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", "WMN", 
"WMN"), COU = c("AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS", 
"AUS", "AUS", "AUS", "AUS"), TIME_FORMAT = c("P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", 
"P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", 
"P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y", "P1Y"), obsTime = c("1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2004"), obsValue = c(434, 398, 225, 345, 544, 
726, 1099, 1607, 1377, 1018, 946, 873, 1131, 903, 1230, 2939, 
0, 0, 2, 24), OBS_STATUS = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), migrants = c(434, 398, 225, 345, 
544, 726, 1099, 1607, 1377, 1018, 946, 873, 1131, 903, 1230, 
2939, 0, 0, 2, 24)), .Names = c("CO2", "VAR", "GEN", "COU", "TIME_FORMAT", 
"obsTime", "obsValue", "OBS_STATUS", "migrants"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is my whole code including two attempts to solve the problem on my own, which do not work, because they just copy the "obsValue" column or give me a column which says TRUE or FALSE. Notice that R will need pretty much time to load the dataset.

```
library(OECD)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

search_dataset("migration")
MIG<- get_dataset("MIG")
get_data_structure("MIG")

MIG$migrants <- if(MIG$VAR == "B11")MIG$migrants<-MIG$obsValue else MIG$migrants<-NA


MIG_long <- mutate(MIG,migrants=VAR=="B11")
if(MIG_long$migrants==T)MIG_long$migrants<-MIG_long$obsValue else MIG_long$migrants<-NA
```

I am hoping that this question is not to low for you and that you can "work" with my explanation. Nevertheless, if you have any questions please ask me.

Best wishes,
Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` to `spread` the `VAR` and `obsValue` into columns. If you do want one year per row, as @atiretoo highighted, you can simply remove the `migrants` column to get unique values per year.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

MIG %>% 
  select(-migrants) %>%
  spread(VAR, obsValue)

     CO2 obsTime   B11   B12
   (chr)   (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1    AFG    1999   434     0
2    AFG    2000   398     0
3    AFG    2001   225     2
4    AFG    2002   345    NA
5    AFG    2003   544    NA
6    AFG    2004   726    24
7    AFG    2005  1099    NA
8    AFG    2006  1607    NA
9    AFG    2007  1377    NA
10   AFG    2008  1018    NA
11   AFG    2009   946    NA
12   AFG    2010   873    NA
13   AFG    2011  1131    NA
14   AFG    2012   903    NA
15   AFG    2013  1230    NA
16   AFG    2014  2939    NA
```

Comment: That's close but OP only wants 1 row per year?